# How to handle UK date format string (dd-mm-yyyy) in SSRS report?

Tags: date, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

It should be a easy problem but surprisingly I could not find a useful answer so please bear with me.

So I fetch the date string(dd-mm-yyyy) from SQL and because the column is `nvarchar` so what I get is a string data type.

What I need is to convert it to date data type and surprisingly it is harder than I can imagine in SSRS report. It seems there is not any build-in function can easily handle the UK format date string.

For example, if I do `CDate("26/03/2018")` it will convert nicely but if I do `CDate("03/26/2018")` it will give me error.

My current solution is to convert the type in SQL but I prefer not to handle the presentation in SQL.

I tried to change language culture and calendar in SSRS but none of them worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting the date in SQL is by far the best way in my opinion. People get hung up about what should go in the presentation layer but this isn't presentation anyway, you're modifying data.

Anyway, if you really want to do this in SSRS, you can with something like this

```
=DateSerial(
            RIGHT(Fields!myUKDate.Value,4),                
            MID(Fields!myUKDate.Value,4,2),
            LEFT(Fields!myUKDate.Value,2)
)
```